# Status 404 error on AJAX list request in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, http-status-code-404

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>
    ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get(
        '/ajax-users/{$id}',
        'DashboardController@indexUsersAjax'
    )->name('ajax.users.index')
        ->middleware(['permission:Access Client Details Edit']);
```

Controller

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource Ajax.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return json
 */
public function indexUsersAjax($id)
{
    $users = User::all();

    $defaultUser = Clients::find($id)
        ->default_user;

    return response()->json($users, $defaultUser);
}
```

AJAX

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('ajax.users.index',[1]) }}",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }});
```

Result on developer tools

```
GET http://localhost:8123/ajax-users/1 404 (Not Found)
Error: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

I have added the Laravel code which I'm working on, couldnt find issue where doing wrong.

Comment: Is the controller executing? Does it execute the `Client::find` query?

Comment: @namelivia I checked on Laravel tool bar on browser, it has not been run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters in Laravel routes don't include a dollar sign.

Replace `'/ajax-users/{$id}'` with `'/ajax-users/{id}'` and it should work.

In addition, the second parameter of `response()->json()` is the HTTP status. If you want to return both variables you have to put them into an array, for example:

```
return response()->json([$users, $defaultUser]);
```

Comment: 404 error sorted with above solution, now 500 error. what may be the reason?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If this doesn't fix it, what's the exact error you get?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `$` from $id inthe route definition:

```php
Route::get(
    '/ajax-users/{id}',
    'DashboardController@indexUsersAjax'
)->name('ajax.users.index')
    ->middleware(['permission:Access Client Details Edit']);
```

Delete if present the file `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`

Execute: `php artisan route:list | grep /ajax-users/{id}` and check it is present

Comment: 404 error sorted with above solution, now 500 error. what may be the reason?

Comment: Check the message added to your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file when you call the route, the reason should be there, if you want add it to the question.